# Appending crontab using ssh and sudo without root credentials

Tags: bash, ssh, sshpass

I have two servers say server A and server B. I have a sudo user say user1 with full privileges on server A and B. I am trying to append the crontab entry of root from server A to server B with the following command. But it's appending on A. I need to append it on server B.

Please find the command below which I am running on server A which should login to server B and append crontab entry of B. Instead its appending on A only.

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'password' /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l user1 \ 
10.10.10.10 -t 'echo password' | sudo -S  bash -c 'echo "30 10 * * * sh test.sh" >> /var/spool/cron/root'
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the whole command that you want to run remotely in quotes, escaping nested quotes - otherwise, piping will be interpreted locally.

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l user1 10.10.10.10 \
-t "echo password | sudo -S bash -c 'echo \"30 10 * * * sh test.sh\" >> /var/spool/cron/root'"
```

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Hi landa, when the execute the above command, i am getting the below error             bash: echo password: command not found